# UIGestureRecogniser in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a `UICollectionView` in my app, with a footer at the bottom containing an image. I would like to make it so that you can scroll to the bottom of the `UICollectionView`, and then if you do a further swipe down, it scrolls to below the footer image to a `UIScrollView`. Obviously you could then scroll up and down the `UIScrollView` and once you are at the top, you can swipe back up and it will jump to above the footer image again.

I assume I would have to use a `UIGestureRecogniser` to detect the swipe up and then add an if statement to check that the user is currently right at the bottom of the collection view?

Hopefully I have explained this well enough. If someone could provide some example code I would really appreciate it!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand.. Do you have a scroll view with image in the footer of collection view? Anyway not need to use gesture recognizer, check `-scrollViewDidEndDragging: willDecelerate:`:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, ScrollDirection) {
    ScrollDirectionDown,
    ScrollDirectionUp
};

@interface ViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollWithImageView;

@property (nonatomic) double lastContentOffset;
@property (nonatomic) ScrollDirection scrollDirection;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate {
    if (decelerate && scrollView == self.scrollWithImageView) {
        if (self.scrollDirection == ScrollDirectionDown) {
           // swipe down
        }
        else {
           // swipe up
        }
    }
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (scrollView == self.scrollWithImageView) {
        // scroll direction
        if (self.lastContentOffset < scrollView.contentOffset.y) {
            self.scrollDirection = ScrollDirectionDown;
        }
        else if (self.lastContentOffset > scrollView.contentOffset.y) {
            self.scrollDirection = ScrollDirectionUp;
        }

        self.lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    }
}

@end
```